# turn_counter does not reset jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I'm trying to build a jQuery Tic-tac-toe game. I'll paste the entire thing so you only have to use 1 file. The issue I'm having is that after each win/tie, the `clearboard()` function needs to reset the board as well as all assigned classes from the previous game. Now it technically does it correctly, but only for 1 round, as soon as round 2 comes, the whole program starts the glitch, it begins to increment by 2 and then start new games with classes already added and counters already incremented.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Simple Tic-Tac-Toe game built using HTML5, JavaScript, jQuery, and CSS." />
        <meta name="keywords" content="tic-tac-toe, game, html5, javascript, jquery, css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width" />
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: italic;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
            body {
                font-size: 1.3em;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
            body {
                font-size: 1.1em;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
            body {
                font-size: 0.8em;
            }
        }
        table {
            margin: 0 auto;
            cursor: default;
            border-spacing: 0;
            width: 23em;
            height: 30em;
        }
        td {
            padding: 0;
            width: 33.3%;
            height: 33.3%;
            font-size: 8em;
            text-align: center;
        }
        table, td { /* by giving both a 1px border, everything gets a 2px border on all sides */
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        body, td:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: gray;
        }
        body, td.taken:hover {
            cursor: default;
            background-color: inherit;
        }
        td.win {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        </style>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // JQuery starts here.......
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var turn_counter = 0;
                var xWins = 0;
                var oWins = 0;
                var ties = 0;
                clearBoard();

                function move(){
                    $(this).off('click');

                    if(turn_counter % 2 == 0) 
                    {
                        $(this).text("x");
                        $(this).addClass("x");
                    } else if(turn_counter % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        $(this).text("o");
                        $(this).addClass("o");
                    };

                    check_board();
                    showScores();
                    turn_counter++;
                    console.log(turn_counter);
                }

                function showScores(){
                    $('#xWins').text(xWins);
                    $('#oWins').text(oWins);
                    $('#ties').text(ties);
                }

                function check_board(){
                    if(turn_counter === 9){
                        alert("It's a TIE!!!");
                        ties++;
                        turn_counter = 0;
                        clearBoard();
                    } else if (
                        $('#1').hasClass('x') && $('#2').hasClass('x') && $('#3').hasClass('x') ||
                        $('#4').hasClass('x') && $('#5').hasClass('x') && $('#6').hasClass('x') ||
                        $('#7').hasClass('x') && $('#8').hasClass('x') && $('#9').hasClass('x') ||
                        $('#1').hasClass('x') && $('#4').hasClass('x') && $('#7').hasClass('x') ||
                        $('#2').hasClass('x') && $('#5').hasClass('x') && $('#8').hasClass('x') ||
                        $('#3').hasClass('x') && $('#6').hasClass('x') && $('#9').hasClass('x') ||
                        $('#1').hasClass('x') && $('#5').hasClass('x') && $('#9').hasClass('x') ||
                        $('#3').hasClass('x') && $('#5').hasClass('x') && $('#7').hasClass('x'))
                    {
                            alert("Player X has won!!!");
                            xWins++;
                            turn_counter = 0;
                            clearBoard();
                    } else if (
                        $('#1').hasClass('o') && $('#2').hasClass('o') && $('#3').hasClass('o') ||
                        $('#4').hasClass('o') && $('#5').hasClass('o') && $('#6').hasClass('o') ||
                        $('#7').hasClass('o') && $('#8').hasClass('o') && $('#9').hasClass('o') ||
                        $('#1').hasClass('o') && $('#4').hasClass('o') && $('#7').hasClass('o') ||
                        $('#2').hasClass('o') && $('#5').hasClass('o') && $('#8').hasClass('o') ||
                        $('#3').hasClass('o') && $('#6').hasClass('o') && $('#9').hasClass('o') ||
                        $('#1').hasClass('o') && $('#5').hasClass('o') && $('#9').hasClass('o') ||
                        $('#3').hasClass('o') && $('#5').hasClass('o') && $('#7').hasClass('o'))
                    {
                            alert("Player O has won!!!");
                            oWins++;
                            turn_counter = 0;
                            clearBoard();
                    }
                }

                function clearBoard(){
                    showScores();
                    $("td").text('')
                    $("td").removeAttr('class');
                    $("td").on('click', move);
                    turn_counter = 0;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!!!!</h1>
        <h2>jQuery Tic-Tac-Toe</h2>
        <p>Score: <span id="xWins"></span> - <span id="oWins"></span><br>Tie Count: <span id="ties"></span></p>
        <table>
            <caption>Match Arena</caption>
            <tr>
                <td id="1"></td>
                <td id="2"></td>
                <td id="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="4"></td>
                <td id="5"></td>
                <td id="6"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="7"></td>
                <td id="8"></td>
                <td id="9"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the order of function calls in your `move` function. If a player has won, you're calling `clearBoard` from `check_board` and directly afterwards your increasing the `turn_counter` via `turn_counter++` in `move` even though no new move has happened.

Furthermore some fields may have double click handlers, because you're only removing them on clicked fields. If a field is not clicked in the previous round, it has two handlers attached. You can prevent this by calling `off` in `clearBoard`
like that: `$("td").off('click').on('click', move);`.

I made a fiddle and tried to fix these issues: http://jsfiddle.net/qpfc455w/

Comment: it worked. But i'm little confused as to your explanation. Thank you very much, but could you walk me through it again please?

Comment: You added a click handler to call the move function on every field at start. You removed this handler is a field was clicked. When the game was over, you added the click handler again. But it wasn't removed on some fields, because they might not have been clicked. I'm preventing this by removing them all in `clearBoard` like that: `$("td").off('click').on('click', move);`. Does that make sense to you? ;)

Comment: Yes, now it does, thank you for explaining it to me. I appreciate the help.